# Complex nonlinear differential equation

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following nonlinear differential equation:
$$\ddot z(t)-\sin(z(t))=0$$
where $z(t)$ is a complex variable.
The solution of the same equation with $z(t)$ real, is a function of Jacobi amplitude integral. What happens when $z(t)=z_0(t)+iz_1(t)$?

Comment: I don't think that anything happens; the same formula should give the solution in this case too, except that the modulus of the Jacobi elliptic function might be any complex number (instead of just a real number between 0 and 1).